# How to scan a external hard disk with RAW file system for viruses

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, virus, raw

I have  a 1TB external hard disk (HD) that I lent to my friend to give me some folders. It worked normally for him.

When I got it back, I plugged it in my laptop and the laptop wouldn't read it. I tried different laptops and cables. I even removed the HD from its casing and used an external connector, but still no luck. The error that always popped: You need to format the disk before you can use it. So I figured this might be software related.

Of course the first thing recommended was using `chkdsk`. But that also failed with the following error:

```bsh
C:\WINDOWS\system32> chkdsk D: /f
The type of the file system is FAT32.
An error occurred while reading the file allocation table (FAT 1).
An error occurred while reading the file allocation table (FAT 2).
There are no readable file allocation tables (FAT).
```

So I tried [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk-7.2-WIP.win.zip) which is a console app that allows changing the file system (not sure, I saw several YouTube tutorials using it). Using it I was able to view the content of the disk. So I noticed some of the folders I know are on the HD were duplicated but as executables.
For example: `Media` -> `Media.exe`.

Now I recognize this behavior: This is the doing of a nasty virus.

The tool (TestDisk) was supposed to be able to fix the HD, but it also failed (or maybe I didn't know how to use it properly for my case). I thought I could fix it then clean it. Since that failed maybe I should do things in revers: clean from viruses then attempt to fix it.

So my question is: Is there a way to scan a hard disk that is RAW for viruses?

P.S: My end goal is re-using the HD without losing any data, so any suggestions to that end are welcome even if they do not answer the main question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the partition table was wiped.  If TestDisk was unable to restore the partition table, you are likely, simply out of luck.  It's entirely possible there isn't actually a virus but just an artifact of the partition table being wiped.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the problem specifically is? So that I could better use TestDisk?

Comment: Your data is lost. Why not format the disk and forget about it?

Comment: @mohdhamm - As I said it sounds like your partition table was wiped.  I assume TestDisk indicate something to this effect when you ran it.

Comment: TestDisk asks me to specify if the partition it found is Primary, Digital, etc.. after setting it to P, TestDisk will run (though finishes instantly) and claims that I have to reboot for the changes to take effect. Alas, changes do not happen. I managed to copy folders using TestDisk, which is great. I guess after that I will format to re-use.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, scanning a RAW disk for viruses is not an option as no antivirus provides this service. (as far as my search goes and what this lovely community knows)

I managed to save some data using TestDisk: when TestDisk asks to specify the partitions, there is an option (press `P`) to view content of selected partition. In viewer mode, you can also copy folders from the disk to anywhere.

I copied some, and will continue to copy the rest. When done I will try to format the disk in the hopes that it's still usable.

Thanks